# Sending developed dom through chrome extension to a webservice

Tags: web-services, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create an extension to send the developed dom of the current tab to a web service at the push of a button, any one knows how I would go about it? methodology,code or simple advice will be appreciated.

I am noob :(

Comment: What do you mean by dom? Html? JS object?

Comment: html, but after the js has been excuted and the content is fully devleoped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `innerHTML`:

```
var html = document.getElementById("element1").innerHTML;
```

Comment: But I am not sure if this gives you the fully developed dom, does it? I am on my phone so have not tested it yet.

Comment: @Max It returns fully developed, the only tricky moment is if you need to catch when it is fully developed (which is impossible in general case).

Comment: mate, it only sends "document"  to the server what am I doing wrong?

Comment: this works  for me now                                                                   document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML